# Kraken API <-> PHP withdrawl issue

Tags: php, api, bitcoin

I need help with the kraken API. I have created the connection and I am able to trade various pairs but now I need to make an automatic withdraw using their API. For the trading pairs I have the following running which buys 0.002 BTC using EURO

```
$res = $kraken->QueryPrivate('AddOrder', array(
    'pair' => 'XBTEUR', 
    'type' => 'sell', 
    'ordertype' => 'market', 
    'volume' => '0.002', 
));

print_r($res);
```

Now... how do I withdraw 0.002 btc using the api and sending these to my wallet: 1BujYrWGkzFdmecXUNgj8nE13gwXtxZxKZ

I can't seem to find this specific information anywhere  :(

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, this was the code I needed:

```
$res = $kraken->QueryPrivate('Withdraw', array(
    'asset' => 'XBT', 
    'key' => 'withdrawal key name here', 
    'amount' => '0.002', 
));

print_r($res);
```

Where as the key, was the name of the account which contained the wallet I wanted to withdraw fund to.

Comment: So the key was: 1BujYrWGkzFdmecXUNgj8nE13gwXtxZxKZ ? What is the name of account like your kraken username?